# XSLT, Appending previous data to the next iteration of a for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I'm in need of a particular solution to my XSLT and I've struggling to figure out how to get it to work. Right now my XML is structured like this

```
<DataX>
   <DataY>
       <fieldy>A</fieldy>
       <fieldx>B</fieldx>
       <Data1>
           <field1>1</field1>
           <field2>2</field2>
       </Data1>
       <Data2>
           <field3>3</field3>
           <field4>4</field4>
       </Data2>
       <Data3>
           <field5>5</field5>
           <field6>6</field6>
       </Data3>
   </DataY>
</DataX>
```

What I need to do is append the contents of `<DataY> <field1> <field2>` to every instance of the inner data fields. Without altering the original XML

Like this

```
A B 1 2    A B 3 4    A B 5 6
```

Like so, I added spaces for clarity.

I've tried some inner for-each statements and few other things. I've not to experience with XSLT but maybe I'm over thinking it. I'm just not sure how to obtain the A B data once a pass has been made using a for-each. Any Thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide desired output XML?

Comment: And well-formed input, please :-)

Comment: Are the those ugly `**` really in the input document?

Comment: Is `<fieldy>A</fieldx>` the actual (non-well-formed) XML, or is this a typo?

Comment: I apologize for the typos, I've fixed them. I'm actually just placing my output to the preview window using Xpad. I plan to place it in a txt file. I don't need an outputed XML.

Comment: Your question is still unclear.  Is the `A B 1 2  A B 3 4 ...` string the exact desired output?  If not, edit the post to show EXACTLY what you want output.  Don't add spaces if you don't want them in the output.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution that is the simplest and shortest so far. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vPrefix">
  <xsl:for-each select="/*/DataY/*[not(starts-with(name(),'Data'))]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*/*[starts-with(name(),'Data')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($vPrefix, .)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<DataX>
    <DataY>
        <fieldy>A</fieldy>
        <fieldx>B</fieldx>
        <Data1>
            <field1>1</field1>
            <field2>2</field2>
        </Data1>
        <Data2>
            <field3>3</field3>
            <field4>4</field4>
        </Data2>
        <Data3>
            <field5>5</field5>
            <field6>6</field6>
        </Data3>
    </DataY>
</DataX>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result** (no intervening spaces as they were added in the question "for clarity"):

```
AB12AB34AB56
```

Comment: I have a good understanding of what your doing here, however on your line   xsl:for-each select="/*/DataY/*[starts-with(name(),'field')]   I see what your doing here, however I oversimplified my example. the word field work for one instance, however in my XML I have 70 unique field names like <IDNum> <Birthday> ect.   Could I add those names to that line of code followed by a comma? Or is a solution more simple then that that could catch all of those lines in vPrefix?

Comment: Thanks man, I'll edit your provided code and give it shot! =)   I'll keep ya posted.

Comment: Thanks man, while I didn't use everything you gave me, it was the insight needed to finish the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should get started with this transform.

---

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[2]/following-sibling::*" mode="data"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="data">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(../*[1],../*[2],*[1],*[2])"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on this input:

```
<DataX>
   <DataY>
       <fieldx>A</fieldx>
       <fieldy>B</fieldy>
       <Data1>
           <field1>1</field1>
           <field2>2</field2>
       </Data1>
       <Data2>
           <field3>3</field3>
           <field4>4</field4>
       </Data2>
       <Data3>
           <field5>5</field5>
           <field6>6</field6>
       </Data3>
   </DataY>
</DataX>
```

It produces:

```
AB12AB34AB56
```

Comment: @Treemonkey, well provide your own then. This is the fastest I've been able to produce at the moment.

Comment: @Dimitre: elegance was @Treemonkey wishes :P. I don't think my exmple is such bad :(

Comment: empo's code worked, but its an amazing piece I could not quite understand. Thanks for everones help and I apologize in advance for the formatting issues.

Comment: @Bryan, did not read you added spaces just for clarity :). Edited my code for correctness. The 'amazing' code above just makes use of positional information and location path abbreviations; at first seen, it's a bit unreadable, but it dependens from the structure of the input document only, not from the element names. Thanks for your feedback anyway.

Comment: I actually have another issue if anyone wants to try for some rep =)   I cant seem to get the output mode to text to work correctly, its only showing one line of text from 25 that are actually produced in the XML. Any thoughts?